# Quando deleto o nome na model não é mostrado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Fiz uma ação para deletar e deleta, mas no View delete não aparece o valor do campo, que vem da model. Esse é o cshtml:

```
@model TreinamentoCrud.Models.Cidade

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Cidade</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nome)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.nome)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

e esse é o controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            DeleteCidadeAsync deleteCidade = new DeleteCidadeAsync();

            await deleteCidade.DeleteCidade(id);

            return View();
        }
```

por mais que seja delete, o atributo no método está como **[HttpPost]**. É normal isso? Veja nesse screenshot o que eu estou dizendo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que a Propriedade nome está vazia e deveria aparecer **Los Angeles**

**EDIT1**

Fiz assim e continua a mesma coisa

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            GetCidadesAsync cidade = new GetCidadesAsync();

            var model = await cidade.GetCidades();

            return View();
        }

        // POST: Cidade/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id, Cidade cidade)
        {
            try
            {
                DeleteCidadeAsync deleteCidade = new DeleteCidadeAsync();

                await deleteCidade.DeleteCidade(id, cidade);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Meu método está assim agora

```
public class DeleteCidadeAsync
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public async Task DeleteCidade(int id, Cidade cidade)
        {
            string url = $"http://localhost:56137/api/DeleteCidade/{id}";
            await client.DeleteAsync(url);
        }
    }
```

Veja dessa forma e da anterior, ambas estão deletando. Só não mostra o nome do cara a ser deletado.

Comment: O seu problema é que o DisplayFor não está exibindo o valor da propriedade nome da model?

Comment: @NetinhoSantos, isso não mostraria(`model => model.nome`)?

Comment: Veja que sua action get não está retornando seu modelo. return View(model);

Comment: @NetinhoSantos, se eu jogo model dá erro. Vou pegar o erro novamente e postar

Answer (score 1):

Veja bem, você está deletando a cidade já, e se você quer mostrar algum dado dessa cidade, você precisa ter dois métodos Deletar, um GET (para mostrar as informações da cidade) e um POST (para confirmar a exclusão):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        SuaClasseDeBuscarCidadesbusca = new SuaClasseDeBuscarCidades();

        Cidade cidade = busca.SeuMetodoQueBuscaCidade(id);

        return View(cidade);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Delete")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmDelete(int id)
    {
        DeleteCidadeAsync deleteCidade = new DeleteCidadeAsync();

        await deleteCidade.DeleteCidade(id);

        return RedirectToView("Index");
    }
```

O método post deve ser chamado ao clicar no botão Delete, que confirma a remoção da cidade.

Comment: faltou o `ActionName`, assim vai dar erro, dois métodos, mesmo nome e ambos esperam 1 `int`

Comment: Opa! Verdade cara, escrevi direto aqui e nem me atentei. Valeuzão!